# jQuery permanently add class on an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have the simple bit of jQuery that adds a class to a paragraph when the value of a hidden input changes to 1:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#acf_success_sent").val() == 1){

  $("#acf_verified").addClass('gone');

  }
 });
```

As far as I know this should work, but as the value only changes briefly, i think the class is only added until the value changes again, so it's not noticeable. How can I get the class to stick.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "as the value only changes briefly"? the code seems pretty straightforward to me

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere in your code, as your example would add the class permenantly (unless you are removing it again elsewhere).

Comment: The hidden value was being generated elsewhere, apologies for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shouldn't be doing anything, unless the value is 1 on DOM ready (because that's the only time it will check it). If you want it to check the value constantly, change it to an onchange event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#acf_success_sent").change(function(){
    if ($("#acf_success_sent").val() == "1"){
     $("#acf_verified").addClass('gone');
     }
   });

 });
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer however I believe the hidden value is only changing intermittently. The value changes on successful submission of a form. I've contacted the developer. Thanks for your help.